# Where is "Post-completion Workflow Activities" in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: workflow, error, workflow-activity

I am having the same problem(or seems to be the same error) as in this [article](http://sharepointmadeeasy.blogspot.com/2008/10/workflow-error-system-account-error-has.html)  but I not sure where to check for this.

I am using sharepoint 2010 and made a custom workflow through Visual Studios 2010.

I cannot find what they are talking about.

Comment: Where is it in 2007? It's not on the association settings page. I'm trying to set it in a SP Designer workflow.

Answer (score 1):

The option discussed in the article is part of the Workflow Association process when you configure a workflow on a list or library. The first screen (which is standard for all workflows) has an option where you can set that the workflow completion also sets content approval (its just a checkbox) on the same form where you define if you wnat the workflow to start manually, automatically, etc.

Comment: This setting is not there in Sharepoint 2010 Foundation

Comment: Content approval is a publishing feature so yes, this option is only available on SharePoint Server 2010, but it is also only applicable on site with publishing features enabled.